# Parsing non-curly braced unicode emoji in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, unicode, emoji

I'm receiving some text from an API that I don't have control over. When I receive emoji they are not encoded correctly for Ruby. Here's an example of what I'm receiving:

- encoded: "\u1F44C"
- decoded: "ὄC"

Ruby doesn't handle unicode with more than 4 hex characters unless you use curly braces. So "\u{1F44C}" would correctly be decoded as .

**How can I convert the output of the API into a format that Ruby can correctly decode?**

Comment: What does the actual API response look like, before Ruby touches it (from e.g. curl)? What is its encoding? Are you getting e.g. the four bytes that represent `` in UTF-8 (0xF0 0x9F 0x91 0x8C), or are you getting the literal characters `\ `, `u`, `1`, ... (which would be 7 bytes)?

Comment: @Jordan I just made an API request within the browser and received this JSON payload: `{ "text": "OK\u1F44C let me see." }` The response headers are: `Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: So in that response `\u1F44C` is the 7 bytes `\ `, `u`, `1`, etc.?

Comment: @Jordan `\u1F44C` are the 7 bytes I'm looking at.

Comment: What you're dealing with here is a broken API. This isn't a Ruby problem, it's a JSON encoder problem. Per [the JSON spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-7), "To escape an extended character that is not in the Basic Multilingual Plane [i.e. U+0000 through U+FFFF], the character is represented as a 12-character sequence, encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair." The correct encoding of `` would be `\uD83D\uDC4C`. Any compliant JSON parser would produce the same output you're seeing. You should report a bug to the API vendor.

Comment: Thanks, reporting to the vendor!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're dealing with here is a broken API. This isn't a Ruby problem, it's a JSON encoder problem. Per [the JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7):

> If the character is in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed by the lowercase letter `u`, followed by four hexadecimal digits that encode the character's code point. The hexadecimal letters `A` though `F` can be upper or lower case.  So, for example, a string containing only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as "`\u005C`".
>
> ...
>
> To escape an extended character that is not in the Basic Multilingual Plane, the character is represented as a 12-character sequence, encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair.  So, for example, a string containing only the G clef character (U+1D11E) may be represented as "`\uD834\uDD1E`".

So the correct encoding of  would be `\uD83D\uDC4C`. Any compliant JSON parser would produce the same output you're seeing. You should report a bug to the API vendor—you're almost certainly not their only customer experiencing this problem.

If you can't get the API vendor to fix their API, your only recourse short of implementing your own JSON parser (or ditching the vendor) is to attempt to fix the JSON response using regular expressions. Something like this works, but *will be* susceptible to false positives, meaning some valid JSON would get mangled:

```
require "json"

def mangle_json(str)
  str.gsub(/\\u([0-9a-f]{5,6})/i) do
    begin
      $1.to_i(16).chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
    rescue RangeError
      $&
    end
  end
end

bad_json = '{"text":"OK\u1F44C let me see."}'

puts JSON.parse(bad_json)["text"]
# => OKὄC let me see.

puts JSON.parse(mangle_json(bad_json))["text"]
# => OK let me see.
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/GnFp/1